# Why does the Number Api return a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is an api called Numbers Api and I want to fetch the `"http://numbersapi.com/42"` for the number fact. But when I do `response.json()` I get a weird error

This is the code I use:

```
    let x = fetch("http://numbersapi.com/42");
    console.log(x);

    x.then( response => {
        return response.json()
    }).then(data =>{
        console.log(data) 
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e) 
    })
```

This is the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 3

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: That address does not return JSON.

Comment: Change `response.json()` to `response.text()`

Comment: might also be a https problem ?

Answer (score 3):

The API doesn't return JSON. It returns this:

```
"42 is the number of US gallons in a barrel of oil."
```

JSON would look like:

```
{ "message": "42 is the number of US gallons in a barrel of oil." }
```

You need to use `response.text` to extract the pure text of the response.

```
let x = fetch("http://numbersapi.com/42");

x.then(response => response.text())
```